# Configuring multiple sites on nginx server

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I would like to configure multiple websites on my nginx server. My configuration under /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default is as below :

```
  server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        server_name _;

        root /var/www/html/MyWebsite;

        location / {
          try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location /admin {
           alias /var/www/html/MyWebsiteAdmin;
           try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

My website is deployed at www.mywebsite.com. I am able to access www.mywebsite.com but not able to access www.mywebsite.com/admin due to few errors like, it cannot load js and css files eg: www.mywebsite.com/inline.bundle.js, www.mywebsite.com/theme.css etc. So, It is trying to access js and css files from www.mywebsite.com but not from www.mywebsite.com/admin/inline.bundle.js. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: for multiple site you have to create new *.conf file with new domain or subdomain

Comment: What is the issue, you never posted any error or logs?

Comment: you have to create new *.conf file for multiple site 
now if you want to run multiple site on single domain then make multiple folder in root folder and write rewrite rule for all

example`location /example1 { index index.html index.php;try_files $uri $uri/ @example1; if ($uri ~ "^/index.php/admin.*$"){rewrite ^/index.php/admin(.*) /admin$1 redirect;} if ($uri ~ "^/index.php"){rewrite /  redirect;}}
  location @example1 { rewrite ^/example1/(.*) /example1/index.php/$1;}
`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have edited question to add the errors iam getting and will be helpful for the other users viewing this question

Comment: @AnkitGujarati I have edited question to add the errors iam getting, is there anyway that i can add rewrite  rules to redirect those js/css requests to www.mywebsite.com/admin

Comment: Why add redirect in nginx for this? You should be fixing your website to properly use the JS and CSS paths

Comment: location ~* \.(?:ico|js|css|gif|jpe?g|png|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|tsv)$ {
    root /var/www/html/MyWebsite/; # put your path of js/css
    expires 365d;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
  }

Comment: @AnkitGujarati do i need to add this as a seperate location in the same conf file?

Comment: @TarunLalwani, Its an angular4 project i cannot change paths of it. It will be generated by angular 4.

Comment: So all css and js calls should go to /admin?

Comment: yes add one separate location.
and add  root "main site root folder".
now if you used a gulp or grunt then put 
*root path* as a build path.

Answer (score 0):

/admin are folder then you not need

`location /admin {alias /var/www/html/MyWebsiteAdmin;try_files $uri $uri/ =404;}` 
now  /admin is like www.mywebsite.com/index.php/admin then you have to add rewrite rule of index.php
`location / {index index.html index.php;try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;}location @handler { rewrite / /index.php; }`